# vBulletin manual php code to insert new user

Tags: php, forum, vbulletin

Can i create a new PHP Code to create/insert new user on vBulletin ?
Or the Code is exsist from vBulletin like Function on Wordpress(wp_create_user()) ?

Comment: You'll just need to take a look at vBulletin's method of storage for user-datas in MySQL, check the columns which may or may not be null, and you can then create it

Comment: I was see the table's and the rows vBulletin use. But its too many and i think it can't manualy query into the table...

Answer (score 1):

Open the `/admincp/user.php` and find this string

```
$_REQUEST['do'] == 'add'
```

And you will see there is no single function to add a new user such as `wp_create_user()`.

Comment: Thankz Sempa, i'll try to do that... :)